# Multiple Paragraph in word table in not getting copied in single cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Below code is working fine I am facing basically 2 major issue.

1. Some time it gives error and if I execute line to line also getting error.
2. In word table, I have multiple paragraph in one cell, and I want those multiple paragraph in single cell of excel. Or any other solution which I am not able to conclude.
   I am adding input and output file for your reference.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim WordApp     As Object
Dim WordDoc     As Object
Dim arrFileList As Variant, FileName As Variant
Dim tableNo     As Integer        'table number in Word
Dim tableStart  As Integer
Dim tableTot    As Integer
Dim LastRow     As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'On Error Resume Next

arrFileList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc; *.docx),*.doc;*.docx", 2, _
              "Browse For file containing table To be imported", , True)

If Not IsArray(arrFileList) Then Exit Sub        '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True

'Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

For Each FileName In arrFileList
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    With WordDoc
        tableNo = WordDoc.tables.Count
        tableTot = WordDoc.tables.Count
        If tableNo = 0 Then
            MsgBox WordDoc.Name & " contains no tables", vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
            
        ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
            tableNo = InputBox(WordDoc.Name & " contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
                      "Enter the table To start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
        End If
        
        ' Set the header for the Colums

        With .tables(tableNo)
            Parent.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = .cell(1, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = .cell(2, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = .cell(3, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = .cell(4, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = .cell(5, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = .cell(6, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = .cell(7, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = .cell(8, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = .cell(9, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = .cell(10, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("K" & LastRow).Value = .cell(11, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("L" & LastRow).Value = .cell(12, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("M" & LastRow).Value = .cell(13, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("N" & LastRow).Value = .cell(14, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("O" & LastRow).Value = .cell(15, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("P" & LastRow).Value = .cell(16, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("Q" & LastRow).Value = .cell(17, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("R" & LastRow).Value = .cell(18, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("S" & LastRow).Value = .cell(19, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("T" & LastRow).Value = .cell(20, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("U" & LastRow).Value = .cell(21, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("V" & LastRow).Value = .cell(22, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("W" & LastRow).Value = .cell(23, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("X" & LastRow).Value = .cell(24, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("Y" & LastRow).Value = .cell(25, 1).Range
            
        End With
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
        
        ' Get the date from the tables
        For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot
        
            With .tables(tableStart)
            .cell(1, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("A" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            .cell(2, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("B" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            .cell(3, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("C" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            .cell(4, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("D" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(5, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("E" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(6, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("F" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(7, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("G" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(8, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("H" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(9, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("I" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(10, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("J" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(11, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("K" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(12, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("L" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(13, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("M" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(14, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("N" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(15, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("O" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(16, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("P" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(17, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("Q" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(18, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("R" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(19, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("S" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(20, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("T" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(21, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("U" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(22, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("V" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(23, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("W" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(24, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("X" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(25, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("Y" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            End With
            
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
            
        Next tableStart
        
        .Close False
    End With
    
Next FileName

WordApp.Quit

Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: Input Word]

[image: Output excel]